# How to define function like JQuery $?

Tags: javascript

JQuery is working with $ as a function, I wanted to know, how can I make my own function like that?

And how to make an contractor function in JavaScript?
Like, I make this:

```
window.test = (function () {        
    var test = {
        get: function (selector) {

        }   
    };

    return test;
}());
```

(for example) I want to select a canvas element when I directly call `test()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need like this chaining object.

```js
var myQuery = function (str) {       
  this.str=str;
  this.concate = function(str){
     this.str= this.str+" "+str;
     return this;
  };
  this.to_string = function(){
     return this.str;
  };
  return this;
};
window['$']=myQuery;

alert($('hello').concate(' $').concate('!!').to_string());
alert(myQuery('hello').concate('myQuery').concate('!!').to_string());
```

**Another Scenario:** Declared reference of myQuery to $ directly;

```js
var myQuery = (function (str) {       
  if(typeof window['$'] ==="undefined")
  {
   window['$']=this;
  }
  this.str=str || '';
  this.concate = function(str){
     this.str= this.str+" "+str;
     return this;
  };
  this.to_string = function(){
     return this.str;
  };
  return this;
})();

alert($.concate("From $").to_string());
```

Comment: Nice answer! Is not this possible to make the `window['$']=myQuery` inside the `myQuery` function? Like using the immediately invoked function!

Comment: @Kermani, Sorry,, I didnt get you..I have done some modification..you are talking about it?

Comment: I mean, how is it possible, to put the window['$']=myQuery inside the myQuery function, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/46tr4jo5/

Comment: @Kermani, also updated with other scenario https://jsfiddle.net/46tr4jo5/2/

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your efforts, your answer is so good

Answer (score 2):

The [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39362774/3176270) is correct, but I think I understand what you need, and maybe this answer also help you:

```js
window["$"] = function (selector) {       
  this.s=selector;
  this.changeColor = function(color){
      document.getElementById(this.s).style.background = color;
     return this;
  };
  return this;
};
```

```html
<div id="elementId">
  Change my background.  
</div>

<a onClick="$('elementId').changeColor('red');" href="#">Red</a>
<a onClick="$('elementId').changeColor('blue');" href="#">Blue</a>
<a onClick="$('elementId').changeColor('green');" href="#">Green</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is useful, but as you said, I think the above answer is more complete... Thanks

Comment: @Lash2 Welcome :)

Comment: @HareshVidja Your answer helped me to provide an answer. My problem with your first function was that the function needed to be called out of the function to define $ (I also don't know what did I say. lol)